# How to create pipeline of functions in Spark that have to be applied on a dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, bigdata

I have one spark dataset `Dataset<T>` loaded from Cassandra Table, and I want to apply list of operations (chain or pipeline) on this dataset.

For example:

```
Dataset<T> dataset= sparkSession.createDataset(javaFunctions(spark.sparkContext())
                    .cassandraTable(...));

Dataset<Row> result = dataset.apply(func1()).apply(func2()).apply(func3());
```

func1() will replace null values with most frequent ones.

func2() will add new columns with new values.

func3() ....etc.

What is the best way to apply this pipeline of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your functions accept Datasets and return Datasets, ie. have the signature:

```
public Dataset[U] myMethod(Dataset[T] ds) {
  ...
}
```

Then you can use the `transform` method defined on a Dataset to neatly apply your functions.

```
ds.tranform(myMethod)
  .transform(myMethod1)
  .transform(myMethod2)
```

If the functions are on standard Java objects, eg.

```
public U myMethod(T row) {
  ...
}
```

Then you want the map method defined on a Dataset.

```
ds.map(myMethod)
  .map(myMethod1)
  .map(myMethod2)
```

Full API docs:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to answer of @wade-jensen!

Here is the complete solution:

```
Dataset<myClass> dataset = ....
Dataset<myClass> new_dataset = dataset.transform(method1(someParamters));

private static Function1<Dataset<myClass>, Dataset<myClass>> method1(someParamters) {
    return new AbstractFunction1<Dataset<myClass>, Dataset<myClass>>() {
        @Override
        public Dataset<myClass> apply(Dataset<myClass> dataset) {

           ...... some work here .... 

            return dataset;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply your function to each row you can use "map" operation.